# Unresolved External Symbol how to fix it? abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, unresolved-external

Here's my abstract class Storestate.h:

```
#ifndef STORESTATE_H_
#define STORESTATE_H_

class Store;
class StoreState
{
public:
    virtual void Close(Store&);
    virtual void Open(Store&);
    virtual void Sell(Store&);
};

#endif
```

The Derived class header file ConcreteStateOpened.h:

```
#ifndef CONCRETESTATEOPENED_H_
#define CONCRETESTATEOPENED_H_
#include "StoreState.h"
#include "Store.h"

class ConcreteStateOpened : public StoreState
{
public:
    ConcreteStateOpened() {}
    void Open(Store&) override;
    void Close(Store&) override;
    void Sell(Store&) override;
};

#endif
```

The Dervied class cpp file ConcreteStateOpened.cpp:

```
#include "ConcreteStateOpened.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ConcreteStateOpened::Open(Store &store)
{
    cout << store.Name << " is already opened!" << endl;
}
void ConcreteStateOpened::Close(Store &store)
{
    store.State = ConcreteStateOpened();
}
void ConcreteStateOpened::Sell(Store &store)
{
    std::cout << "Sell Opened";
}
```

I don't know how to fix this. I tried removing override keywords, aswell as virtual ones. Even removing the definition etc. I just need help from pros :,)

Here are the unresolved external symbol errors:

```
1>ConcreteStateOpened.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Close(class Store &)" (?Close@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>Data.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Close(class Store &)" (?Close@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>StateStore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Close(class Store &)" (?Close@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>ConcreteStateOpened.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Open(class Store &)" (?Open@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>Data.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Open(class Store &)" (?Open@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>StateStore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Open(class Store &)" (?Open@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>ConcreteStateOpened.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Sell(class Store &)" (?Sell@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>Data.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Sell(class Store &)" (?Sell@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>StateStore.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall StoreState::Sell(class Store &)" (?Sell@StoreState@@UAEXAAVStore@@@Z)
1>D:\Local-Git-Repos\DesignPatterns\StateC++\StateStore\Debug\StateStore.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make the methods in the abstract base pure virtual.
Also you should add : public virtual destructor, protected default constructor and remove copy/move/assignment constructors

```
#ifndef STORESTATE_H_
#define STORESTATE_H_

class Store;
class StoreState
{
public:
    virtual ~StoreState() = default;
    StoreState(const StoreState&) = delete;
    StoreState(StoreState&&) = delete;
    StoreState& operator=(const StoreState&) = delete;

    virtual void Close(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Open(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Sell(Store&) = 0;
protected:
    StoreState() = default; // prevent accidental creation
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no abstract class in the presented code by you because the class `StoreState` does not contain pure virtual functions.

From the C++ 20 Standard (11.7.3 Abstract classes)

> 2 A virtual function is specified as a pure virtual function by using
> a pure-specifier (11.4) in the function declaration in the class
> definition. [Note: Such a function might be inherited: see below. —
> end note] **A class is an abstract class if it has at least one pure
> virtual function.** [Note: An abstract class can be used only as a
> base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be
> created except as subobjects of a class derived from it (6.2, 11.4). —
> end note] A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with,
> or as if with (11.4.6), the qualified-id syntax

You need either to provide definitions of the  virtual functions declared in the class `StoreState` or to make them pure virtual functions like for example

```
class StoreState
{
public:
    virtual void Close(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Open(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Sell(Store&) = 0;
};
```

Even if a function is declared as a pure virtual function nevertheless you may provide its definition (outside the class definition where it is declared as a pure virtual function) if it is required.

Pay attention to that when you have polymorphic classes then you should declare the destructor also as virtual. For example

```
class StoreState
{
public:
    virtual ~StoreState() = default;

    virtual void Close(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Open(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Sell(Store&) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `StoreState` isn't actually abstract. You have declared `Close`, `Open`, `Sell` as actual virtual functions with definitions. To declare a virtual function with no definition in that class, use the "pure virtual" syntax `= 0`.

Also, it's best practice for a polymorphic class type to have a virtual destructor. And per the Rule Of Five, when you declare a destructor, be sure to think about the copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment. For an interface class, it's often best to just make it uncopyable and unassignable.

```
class StoreState
{
public:
    StoreState() = default;
    StoreState(const StoreState&) = delete;
    StoreState& operator=(const StoreState&) = delete;
    virtual ~StoreState() = default;

    virtual void Close(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Open(Store&) = 0;
    virtual void Sell(Store&) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add virtual to the concrete class methods

```
#ifndef CONCRETESTATEOPENED_H_
#define CONCRETESTATEOPENED_H_
#include "StoreState.h"
#include "Store.h"

class ConcreteStateOpened : public StoreState
{
public:
    ConcreteStateOpened() {}
    virtual void Open(Store&) override;
    virtual void Close(Store&) override;
    virtual void Sell(Store&) override;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Nope, the functions in the derived class are automatically virtual as long as they have the same name and signature as a base class virtual function, whether or not the `virtual` and/or `override` are present. And since it's impossible for an `override` declaration to not be virtual, many C++ programmers consider also writing `virtual` to be redundant.